# How to Show or Hide multiple divs with multiple checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox, show-hide

I have a requirement, that I have multiple check boxes. 
I have a set of checkbox related content which are in `<p>` tags. 
When page loads all the `<p>` tag related content will display.
After when user selects any checkbox 
then only that checkbox related content will display and remaining will hide. 
Next when user selects second checkbox second checkbox related content will display.

Below is the `<p>` tag content like this i have 20 `<p>` tags

```
<p id="sb1">Checkbox content one</p>
<p id="sb2">Checkbox content two</p>

<input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
<input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="">checkme2
```

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    {
        $('#chk1').prop('checked', true);
        $("#sb2,#sb3,#sb4,#sb5,#sb6,#sb7,#sb8,#sb9,#sb10").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#chk2').prop('checked', false);
        $("#sb1,#sb3,#sb4,#sb5,#sb6,#sb7,#sb8,#sb9,#sb10").show();
    }
});
```

Can some one please help me, like this i have 20 checkboxes and 20 `<p>` tags, i tried in many ways .

Please help me in this regard, any help be greatly appreciated..

Comment: I would give your `p` tags a class and then you can just use `$('p.className').hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
   <p id="sb1"  class="p_element">Checkbox content one</p>
   <p id="sb2"  class="p_element">Checkbox content two</p>

   <input name="chk1" class="check_box" type="checkbox" data-ptag="sb1" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
   <input name="chk2"  class="check_box" type="checkbox" data-ptag="sb2" id="chk2" value="">checkme2
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.check_box').change(function(){
if($('.check_box:checked').length==0){
    $('.p_element').show(); //Show all,when nothing is checked
}else{
    $('.p_element').hide();
    $('.check_box:checked').each(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).attr('data-ptag')).show();
    });
  }

});
```

***[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kdc0byxu/)***

Comment: HI Shin,this solution is working fine , this is my exact requirement. Thank you very much.

Comment: HI Shin can you please check this link which i posted today on stackoverflow?How to clear previously selected checkbox values in bootstrap multiselect list box

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var first = true;
$('input[type="checkbox"][name^=chk]').change(function () {
    var $target = $('#sb' + this.id.replace('chk', '')).toggle(this.checked);
    if (first) {
        $('p[id^=sb]').not($target).hide();
        first = false;
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/274vdmb0/)

Comment: HI Arun, very useful answer. and can you please check this question?   How to clear previously selected checkbox values in bootstrap multiselect list box . Please use google to get this link

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Use [jQuery start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and hide all contents first then show respective content.

```
<script>
       $(document).ready(function()
       {
           //hide all contents
           $('p[id^=sb]').hide();

           $('input[id^=chk]').change(function(){

              // get checkbox index
              var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('chk','');

              //show respective contents
              if($(this).is(':checked'))
                $('#sb'+index).show();
              else
                $('#sb'+index).hide();
           });

        });
  </script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/274vdmb0/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, inside you're `script` the `this` scope is the `document` not the `checkboxes`. 
Then, you have to bind the behaviour to the `checkboxes` and above all, use `class` instead of `id`s
or you will get mad
so:

```
<pre>
  <p class="sb">Checkbox content one</p>
  <p class="sb">Checkbox content two</p>
  ...
</pre>

<pre>
  <input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
  <input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="">checkme2
</pre>
```

then:

```
$(function(){

 $("#chk1").on('change', function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
     $(".sb").hide();
     $(".sb").eq(0).show();
 })

 $("#chk2").on('change', function(){
    if(!$(this).prop('checked'))
     $(".sb").eq(0).hide();
     $(".sb").show();
 })
})
```

Here it is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8sm8njjs/1

With your code the situation is kinda tricky, maybe try to explain also what you are trying to achieve

Comment: HI, please check the demo. This is my exact requirement
***[FIDDLE DEMO][1]***


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/kdc0byxu/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oteg4tse/)**

**Html Part:**

```
<pre>
<p id="sb1">Checkbox content one</p>
<p id="sb2">Checkbox content two</p>
<p id="sb3">Checkbox content three</p>
<p id="sb4">Checkbox content four</p>
</pre>

<pre>
<input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
<input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="">checkme2
</pre>
```

**Javascript Part:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('p').hide();

    $('#chk1').change(function(){ 
        var tags=$("#sb1,#sb2");
       if($(this).attr('checked'))
       {
           tags.show();
       }
        else{
           tags.hide();
       }
    });

    $('#chk2').change(function(){ 
       var tags=$("#sb3,#sb4");

       if($(this).attr('checked'))
       {
           tags.show();
       }
        else{
            tags.hide();
       }
    });
});
```